# reading file and putting json file in Nested structure in Go lang with appending extra data

Tags: json, go

I have nested structure one structure coming from reading file and second I'm providing my self and I have to stdout the file. I got the code but I'm having hard time with syntax and logic I'm new to go lang.(the data structure supposed to come from the file)

Comment: @CeriseLimón it was typo

Comment: Obviously code does not compile if it complied i wouldn't ask the question but it does compile and it does give errors if you run it on your machine instead of goplay.

Comment: @CeriseLimón The syntax and logic is wrong but i put the program on playground. I need to read file and structure it for Data part of the json then i have another structure that already comes prebuild in the program. if you look at the code and output you will see what im talking about it.

Answer (score 1):

The program reads the file, but then substitutes something else in for data.  Just put the data in the value marshaled to the output.

```
type Event struct {
    Specversion string    `json:"specversion"`
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"id"` /// uuid
    Source      string    `json:"source"`
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Time        time.Time `json:"time"`
    Data        string    `json:"data"` /* <= change to string */
}

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 1 { //checking for provided argument if the first arg satisfy then use read file
        fmt.Println("Usage : " + os.Args[0] + " file name")
        help()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot read the file or file does not exists")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    e := Event{
        Specversion: "1.0",
        ID:          uuid.New(),
        Source:      "CSS",
        Type:        "", //  user input -p or -u,
        Time:        time.Now(),
        Data:        string(Data), /* <= stuff data into output value */
    }

    out, _ := json.MarshalIndent(e, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

[Run it on the playground to get results as requested in the question](https://go.dev/play/p/M-s-_wEMrr1).

Perhaps the \r\n in the output are the problem. Remove carriage return and line feed from the JSON before encoding the result:

```
replacer := strings.NewReplacer("\r", "", "\n", "")
Data = []byte(replacer.Replace(string(Data)))
```

[Run it on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0bDpGqybskL).

If you intent is to include the JSON as JSON instead of quoting the JSON as string, then use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage):

```
type Event struct {
    Specversion string    `json:"specversion"`
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"id"` /// uuid
    Source      string    `json:"source"`
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Time        time.Time `json:"time"`
    Data        json.RawMessage    `json:"data"` /* <= change to json.RawMessage */
}

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 1 { //checking for provided argument if the first arg satisfy then use read file
        fmt.Println("Usage : " + os.Args[0] + " file name")
        help()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot read the file or file does not exists")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    e := Event{
        Specversion: "1.0",
        ID:          uuid.New(),
        Source:      "CSS",
        Type:        "", //  user input -p or -u,
        Time:        time.Now(),
        Data:        Data, /* <== use data as is */
    }

    out, _ := json.MarshalIndent(e, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

[Run it on the playground to view nested json](https://go.dev/play/p/t9_VVrANtkr).  You show a quoted string in the question, but perhaps this output is what you really want.

Comment: that doesnt work i already have that code. The format does not comeout to the way i want to. I specifically stated that i want nested structure

Comment: @expert.free the output in the question shows the input file as quoted json string, not as nested json.  is the output in the question incorrect or am i misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: When you run code in playground the structure looks good but when you actually put it in the system it doesn't come out the same as output. Im reading file for data part of the struct but it has to have struct i dont want to just read it then marshal it. i need to structure it from file then marshal it.  i edited the code on playground if you want to help figure this out

Comment: thank you but do you see the output example there are slashes \  on data part

Comment: and on play ground the your first quoted code works but in system it doesn't look like same format. I need make exactly the output shown. when i run your first code thats what comes out. `{"specversion":"1.0","id":"86c4c459-3e4e-44f0-9cda-b54599765595","source":"CSS","type":"","time":"2022-09-09T13:14:07.912511-05:00","data":"\r\n{\r\n\"mac_address\": \`