# removing \n \r\n from json in go lang

Tags: json, go

The program reads the file from input json,then appends extra structure within the program. I have everything working but when i printout in my console it has extra n\ r and  spaces in the json. In the playground it doesnt but when i run it from shell it does. The problem how can i removed to match the outcome file.

File thats getting inputted:

```
{
    "mac_address": "",
    "serial_number": "4UW1234",
    "device_type": "STORuhaiul",
    "device_model": "N9ZsdfsdA",
    "part_number": "N9sdfsdfsdf5A",
    "extra_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_type": "ENTITLEMENT_ID",
        "attribute_value": "ABC123JKJUBCDZ"
      }
    ],
    "platform_customer_id": "f850243a4c1911eca07f6db9a",
    "application_customer_id": "88e0ff88c07811ed76c7988eb"
  }
```

Outcome file should be like this exactly quoted(result)

```
{
  "specversion": "1.0",
  "id": "ce20b92d-b45b7-a544-8fe4d8f7ff06",
  "source": "CCS",
  "type": "",
  "time": "2022-08-09T23:59:08.468903+00:00",
  "data": "{\"mac_address\": null, \"serial_number\": \"ADL-DHCI1\", \"device_type\": \"DHCI_STORAGE\", \"device_model\": \"NIMBLE DHCI STORAGE\", \"part_number\": \"60\", \"extra_attributes\": [

{\"attribute_type\": \"ENTITLEMENT_ID\", \"attribute_value\": \"YIZUYYNEYV0LVAU\"}
], \"tag_entities\": [], \"platform_customer_id\": \"a07db1081d5b41eeed59645ee95\", \"application_customer_id\": \"3118643e201cb2c92e8b7aa93178\", \"folder_name\": null}"
}
```

my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Event struct {
    Specversion string    `json:"specversion"`
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"id"` /// uuid
    Source      string    `json:"source"`
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Time        time.Time `json:"time"`
    Data        string    `json:"data"` /// this part supposed to come from the file
}

type Data struct {
    MacAddress            string            `json:"mac_address"`
    SerialNumber          string            `json:"serial_number"`
    DeviceType            string            `json:"device_type"`
    DeviceModel           string            `json:"device_model"`
    PartNumber            string            `json:"part_number"`
    ExtraAttributes       []DeviceAttribute `json:"extra_attributes"`
    PlatformCustomerID    string            `json:"platform_customer_id"`
    ApplicationCustomerID string            `json:"application_customer_id"`
}

type DeviceAttribute struct {
    AttributeType  string `json:"attribute_type"`
    AttributeValue string `json:"attribute_value"`
}

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 1 { //checking for provided argument if the first arg satisfy then use read file
        fmt.Println("Usage : " + os.Args[0] + " file name")
        help()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot read the file or file does not exists")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    e := Event{
        Specversion: "1.0",
        ID:          uuid.New(),
        Source:      "CSS",
        Type:        "", //  user input -p or -u,
        Time:        time.Now(),
        Data:        string(Data),
    }

    out, _ := json.Marshal(e)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}

func help() {
    fmt.Println("help")
}
```

When im running the program  im getting this output from vs code

```
{"specversion":"1.0","id":"c053519-71ef-4a80-a47b-392ac2434f99","source":"CSS","type":"","time":"2022-09-09T14:01:40.2599627-05:00","data":"{\r\n    \"mac_address\": \"\",\r\n    \"serial_number\": \"4UW1234\",\r\n    \"device_type\": \"STOuhaul\",\r\n    \"device_model\": \"N95A\",\r\n    \"part_number\": \"N9Z55A\",\r\n    \"extra_attributes\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"attribute_type\": \"ENTITLEMENT_ID\",\r\n        \"attribute_value\": \"ABC123JV9UBCDZ\"\r\n      }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"platform_cust.....
```

output from shell

```
{"specversion":"1.0","id":"5f5b1841-d99c-4eef-8867-7c09a23d5bb5","source":"CSS","type":"","time":"2022-09-09T19:34:43.802856511Z","data":" \"mac_address\": \"\",\n  \"serial_number\": \"j\",\n  \"device_type\": \"STORAGE\",\n  \"device_model\": \"VIRTUAL\",\n  \"part_number\": \"VIRTUAL\",\n  \"extra_attributes\": [\n    {\n      \"attribute_type\": \"ENTITLEMENT_ID\",\n      \"attribute_value\": \"H6MI9JYNJCOSBL1GTjfgjfjY6P\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"platform_customer_id\": \"b050fa3a49hfghfghfbbf0a2a9c6414efb\",\n  \"application_customer_id\": \"03eda3027f4c11ec8cee12749a9c9018\"\n\n"}
```

[go playcode](https://go.dev/play/p/M-s-_wEMrr1)

Comment: You have json encoded in a string, within json. Is that really what you want?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#MarshalIndent

Comment: I'm inputting file and i want to basically to have it like output provided. I tried to do marshal without indent and same result

Comment: i have nested structure and but data part come from the file.

Comment: You cannot have json output exactly like that, because it is invalid json. Your example has json half string-encoded within json, what do you really want here?

Comment: This is also the exact same question just asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73664562/reading-file-and-putting-json-file-in-nested-structure-in-go-lang-with-appending, is this some sort of homework assignment?

Comment: yes it is the out could css.

Comment: This solves the white spaces but now everything is out of order

Comment: json objects are an unordered collection of key value pairs. There is no order to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove carriage return and line feed from json:

```
replacer := strings.NewReplacer("\r", "", "\n", "")
Data = []byte(replacer.Replace(string(Data)))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0bDpGqybskL

Comment: now the order of the incoming file is corrupted. So im guessing unmarshaling the var doesnt hold the order